# Convert Annotated Image to Binary Mask Image using Polygon Co-ordinate

Tags: python, json, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to Convert Annotated image to Binary mask Image using cordinates present in json file.
Image is Annotated using VGG annotation.

Below are the Actual image, Json data, and the result i want.

[image]

Here are the Cordinates of the above image

```
{"ILSVRC2012_test_00000181.jpg28497":{"filename":"ILSVRC2012_test_00000181.jpg","size":28497,"regions":[{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[55,63,82,103,116,137,140,153,155,160,160,169,199,211,227,236,242,250,255,265,268,278,282,290,303,315,321,329,326,332,337,336,330,324,321,317,317,319,309,285,275,264,262,236,223,207,196,190,183,176,176,190,196,187,158,145,118,94,76,83,94,111,101,87,88,105,79,55],"all_points_y":[102,95,87,69,62,58,58,64,69,76,79,77,80,81,78,77,79,84,90,104,108,113,114,129,147,168,204,252,264,286,302,305,299,288,295,316,327,340,343,345,338,340,346,348,340,337,323,314,310,308,305,301,329,337,331,316,325,330,319,306,289,282,229,159,128,98,98,104]},"region_attributes":{"name":"not_defined","type":"unknown","image_quality":{"good":true,"frontal":true,"good_illumination":true},"animal":"pigeon"}}],"file_attributes":{"caption":"","public_domain":"no","image_url":""}}}
```

[image: I want to Convert the above image in Binary Mask like beolw using that json Cordinate]

Or does any knows any tool which helps to create dataset like this.

Thankyou

**EDIT**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")

area = np.array([
          [55, 102], [63, 95], [82, 87], [103, 69],[116,62 ], [137,58 ],[140,58 ], [153, 64],
          [155,69 ], [160, 76],[160,79 ], [169,77 ],[199, 80], [211,81 ],[227,78 ], [236, 77],
          [242,79 ], [250, 84],[255, 90], [265, 104],[268, 108], [278, 113],[282, 114], [290, 129],
          [303, 147], [315, 168],[321, 204], [329, 252],[326, 264], [332, 286],[337, 302], [336, 305],
          [330, 299], [324, 288],[321,295 ], [317, 316],[317, 327], [319,340],[309, 343], [285, 345],
          [275, 338], [264, 340],[262, 346], [236, 348],[223, 340], [207, 337],[196, 323], [190, 314],
          [183, 310], [176, 308],[176, 305], [190, 301],[196, 329], [187, 337],[158, 331], [145, 316],
          [118, 325], [94, 330],[76, 319], [83, 306],[94, 289], [111, 282],[101, 229], [87, 159],
          [88,128 ], [105, 98],[79, 98],[55, 104]
         ]  )

filled = cv2.fillPoly(img, pts = [area], color =(255,255,255))
cv2.imwrite("mask_pen.jpg",filled)
```

Also used a naive method to make evreything black except 255

```
img = cv2.imread('mask_pen.jpg')
img[img != 255] = 0
```

which gives results like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHNag.jpg)

Comment: You simply have to extract the x and y coordinate lists from the JSON data and then use OpenCV cv2.fillPoly() to draw a white filled polygon on a black background image.

Comment: However, the JSON data does not give the needed dimensions directly. The image would have to be extracted and checked for its dimensions in order to create the needed size for the black background image.

Comment: There are JSON readers for Python. See for example:  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json and https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: Thanks, i will look through the link and cv2.fillPolly() too.

Comment: drawContoura opencv function might work as well

Comment: @fmw42 Hello, now i am able to create a white mask, here is the output https://imgur.com/k7GdoWN  thanks to you,  but as you can see the borders are zig zagged is there a way to improve this, also how do i change the remaining area color to black. Thankyou

Comment: Show your code, so that others can run it and show you how to do what you want. You can use img[mask!=0]=(0,0,0) to make the rest of the image black. To anti-alias the mask, you need to blur it and then do a stretch. I have posted solutions for this on this forum. So search here or Google for it. Or post your code and I can try to fill it in.

Comment: @fmw42, i have added the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to do the filled polygon and antialiasing in Python/OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")

area = np.array([
          [55, 102], [63, 95], [82, 87], [103, 69],[116,62 ], [137,58 ],[140,58 ], [153, 64],
          [155,69 ], [160, 76],[160,79 ], [169,77 ],[199, 80], [211,81 ],[227,78 ], [236, 77],
          [242,79 ], [250, 84],[255, 90], [265, 104],[268, 108], [278, 113],[282, 114], [290, 129],
          [303, 147], [315, 168],[321, 204], [329, 252],[326, 264], [332, 286],[337, 302], [336, 305],
          [330, 299], [324, 288],[321,295 ], [317, 316],[317, 327], [319,340],[309, 343], [285, 345],
          [275, 338], [264, 340],[262, 346], [236, 348],[223, 340], [207, 337],[196, 323], [190, 314],
          [183, 310], [176, 308],[176, 305], [190, 301],[196, 329], [187, 337],[158, 331], [145, 316],
          [118, 325], [94, 330],[76, 319], [83, 306],[94, 289], [111, 282],[101, 229], [87, 159],
          [88,128 ], [105, 98],[79, 98],[55, 104]
         ]  )

filled = np.zeros_like(img)
filled = cv2.fillPoly(filled, pts = [area], color =(255,255,255))

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(filled, (0,0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("filled_polygon.jpg",filled)
cv2.imwrite("filled_polygon_antialiased.jpg",result)

cv2.imshow("filled", filled)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Filled Polygon:

[image]

Antialiased Filled Polygon:

[image]